# Symfony2 form isValid doesn't work

Tags: validation, symfony, symfony-forms, fosuserbundle

My form Type:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('username')
    ;
}
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'MyApp\UserBundle\Entity\User',
    ));
}
```

And controller:

```
    $form = $this->createForm(new OAuthEmailType());
    if ($request->isMethod('POST'))
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form->setData($user);
        $form->bind($request);

        // die($form->getErrorsAsString());
        if ($form->isValid()) // always returns true
        {
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
```

My User entity properties have annotations validation. Also this class extends FOSUserBundle User entity.

And here is the problem. `$form->isValid()` always returns true, but the same form type perfectly works with another controller. Why form is not validated exactly in this controller? What I missed?

Comment: In your posted code you are not calling $form->isValid().  Copy/paste error?

Comment: @Cerad I replaced it by `die($form->getErrorsAsString());` that also shows no errors. I placed it back, look.

Comment: Please post a few lines from the working controller.  I assume you are using the same User object though since you are using FOSUserBundle the I would have expected you to be using the $fosUserManager->createUser() method.  Are you using validation groups?

Comment: @Cerad oh God thank you. I just forgot about validation groups. I added `'validation_groups' => array('Registration')` and it worked! Please add an answer to this question so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My awesome intuition suggests that you need to add the correct validation_group to your form.

Actually just a guess.  See the comments.  But I have had this happen to me as well.